# как расположить "блоки" как на данной картинке?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Пока мой выглядит вот так:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
}

.menu {
    background-color: #008B8B;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.zagolovok {
    background-color: #8B0000;
}

.text-1 {
    background-color: #00008B;
}

.text-2 {
    background-color: #006400;
}

.menu, .text-1, .text-2, .zagolovok {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>display</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <h1>Меню</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="zagolovok">
        <h1>Заголовок</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text-1">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni quaerat ad cum voluptas fugiat, repellendus doloribus ipsam modi eos unde praesentium accusamus beatae! Nobis tempore quidem magni ut accusamus molestiae.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-2">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni quaerat ad cum voluptas fugiat, repellendus doloribus ipsam modi eos unde praesentium accusamus beatae! Nobis tempore quidem magni ut accusamus molestiae.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]